# What is the probability that EA > EC?

Tags: probability

I found this question in one of my books:

> Square $ABCD$ has a length of $1$. Point $E$ is selected inside the square. Segment $EA$ represents the distance between point $E$ and one of the vertices of the square, $A$, and segment $EC$ represents the distance between point $E$ one of the vertices of the square, $C$. What is the probability that $EA > EC$?

Since $E$ can be anywhere on the square, the first thing to focus on is point $E$ being on the perpendicular bisector of $AC, BD$.

[image: img]

If it is on $BD$, then it's equidistant from $A$ and $C$. In this case, neither $EA$ nor $EC$ are greater than each other, but it still adds a possibility to where $E$ can be.

If $E$ is anywhere away from $BD$ and closer to $A$, then $EC > EA.$

If $E$ is anywhere away from $BD$ and closer to $C$, then $EA > EC.$

To me, it seems like there are $3$ total possibilities and there's only one where $EA > EC,$ making it $1/3$ for the answer to the question. In my book, it says the possibility $EA > EC$ is $1/2$, which I don't understand because it indicates that there are $2$ total possibilities, but $E$ being on the perpendicular bisector is still a possibility.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I buy a lottery ticket. There are two possibilities, either I win \$1 million or I get nothing. Does that mean that the probability of winning \$1 million must be 1/2?

Comment: Too many links for potential answerers to chase.

Comment: First, just because there are $n$ possibilities, doesn't mean that each has a probability of $\frac{1}{n}$. They can all have different probabilities. Second there are things that are "possible" but have probability zero. E.g., if I randomly pick a number between $0$ and $1$, the probability that I pick $1/7$ (or any specific number) is $0$. (To see this, note that the probability that I pick an number between $a$ and $b$ is $b-a$). In this case, there are indeed three possibilities, but the probability that the point $E$ is equidistant from $A$ and $C$ is zero.

Comment: I understand your confusion. But how likely is it for $E$ to be on that perp bisector which is a line in a square? In mathematics that probability is zero.

Comment: Your post indicates a naive understanding of probability. Perhaps by telling Readers what book you found this exercise in, you will help them to understand what level of studies the solution should be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume that $A=(0,0), C=(1,1), E=(x,y), 0\le x,y\le 1$. Then your condition means $x^2+y^2>(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2$ or $2x+2y>2$ or $y>1-x$. So the probability is the area of the region of the square above the line $y=1-x$ which (the line) is the diagonal $BD$. That area is $1/2$, so the probability is $1/2$.

One can argue also that the probability that $AE>EC$ must be the same as the probability that $EC>AE$ because of the symmetry of the square and the sum of these probabilities is $1$ (because the probability that $EC=AE$ is $0$; it is the area of the diagonal $BD$). If you want to know more about geometric probability, look [here.](https://brilliant.org/wiki/1-dimensional-geometric-probability/?quiz=1-dimensional-geometric-probability#_=_)